# list (not connected) shared drives on mac via shell

Tags: macos, shell

On my mac I have shared location to my NAS, I see it in the finder.
On the shell, if I enter `ls /Volumes` I only get my hard disk listed but not the NAS, I need to navigate to a folder on my NAS (using the finder window) then it gets listed with previous `ls`.
Any idea how I can access all "not connected" drives I have on my mac via shell?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the use of `dns-sd` in order to retrieve the informations needed to mount it.

Comment: Great `dns-sd -B _afpovertcp._tcp local`
`dns-sd -B _smb._tcp local` did the trick.. thanks dezzeus